# iOS: propagate pan gesture to UITableView

Tags: ios

I have a UITableView, each cell contains a UIScrollView inside. I want to capture the pan gesture inside the UIScrollView to do some stuff, and without affecting the normal behaviour of the table view. eg) swipe up cause the table view to scroll up.

The code snippet:

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {
NSLog(@"handleSwipe");

}
```

In UITableView's cell for row at index path function:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
[picScrollView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

Now I can see the handleSwipe is called but the UITableview stop functioning - it just can't scroll now.

I think the pan event is eaten by the scrollview but I just want it to be propagate to the table view.

Comment: why you want to add a swipeGesture? you can use `UIScrollViewDelegate` to handle you method.

Comment: To expound on what Wongzigii said, you can use the UIScrollViewDelegate's scrollViewDidScroll method to set the UITableView's contentOffset.